# Cakephp Group By pagination is not working

Tags: pagination, group-by, cakephp-1.3

While i'm using "group by" query, the pagination is not showing up.. Only the first page were shows...
If anyone have a solution for this, Please post an example.. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should really post the relevant bits of your code and specify your problem more precisely, so please post the relevant bits of your controller and view (and model if relevant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add GROUP BY clause

```
var $paginate = array(
    'MyModel' => array(
        'limit' => 20,
        'order' => array('week' => 'desc'),
        'group' => array('week', 'home_team_id', 'away_team_id')
    )
);
```

Or on-the-fly from within the action

```
function index() {
    $this->paginate = array(
        'MyModel' => array(
            'limit' => 20,
            'order' => array('week' => 'desc'),
            'group' => array('week', 'home_team_id', 'away_team_id')
        )
    );

}
```